# GridView.count vs GridView.builder Difference In Flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview

What is the difference between `gridview.builder` and `gridview.count` in Flutter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like any other `.builder` [GridView.builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView/GridView.builder.html) create Widgets on demand.

> Creates a scrollable, 2D array of widgets that are created on demand.
> This constructor is appropriate for grid views with a large (or infinite) number of children because the builder is called only for those children that are actually visible.

But [GridView.count](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView/GridView.count.html) allows to directly have `crossAxisCount` that use to count item on single row. Full Grandview will follow this pattern.

> Creates a scrollable, 2D array of widgets with a fixed number of tiles in the cross axis.

When you have the large number of widgets, consider using `GridView.builder` to get better performance. Also, using `gridDelegate` gives you more controls over UI.

You can explore [GridView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html).