# what is the major difference GridView and GridView.builder in flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview, scroll, lazy-loading, builder

I wanted to test the lazy loading in `GridView` and `GridView.builder`, so i made a custom widget called `AnotherText` in which i display a Text and print a `build` word whenever it builds

```
class AnotherText extends StatelessWidget {
  const AnotherText({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build');
    return Text('Hello');
  }
}
```

Then i tried both constructors

```
GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: [
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
          AnotherText(),
        ],
      ),
```

And

```
GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => AnotherText(),
        itemCount: 100,
      ),
```

Both of them build the widget when i scroll, not all the widgets at once, therefore both of them are lazy loading, if it means build widgets only on demand.

So what is the major difference between GridView and GridView.builder?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to flutter documentation for the **builder** constructor:

The builder is suitable for **large data** and also allow you to use the index of data and the return item on demand which give you more control for the data flow.

> This constructor is appropriate for grid views with a large (or
> infinite) number of children because the builder is called only for
> those children that are actually visible.
>
> Providing a non-null itemCount improves the ability of the GridView to
> estimate the maximum scroll extent.
>
> itemBuilder will be called only with indices greater than or equal to
> zero and less than itemCount.

**Other post have explained:**
[GridView.count vs GridView.builder Difference In Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69208509/gridview-count-vs-gridview-builder-difference-in-flutter)

**References:**
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView/GridView.builder.html

Comment: Yes, but i mean the lazy loading, many says that builder does the lazy loading however its both constuctors